# How to link MongoDB and Superset BI and import real time data ？

Tags: postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I have a mongodb on a server 122.xxx.xxx.xxx. The mongodb version is 3.4.1. 
I was asked to pool the **real-time** data from MongoDB to the superset BI to create various dashboards.

I have tried the following way:

Use a Foreign Data Wrapper mongodb + multicorn + yam_fdw o create a foreign table in postgresql

**In Postgresql console:**

```
CREATE EXTENSION multicorn;

CREATE SERVER mongodb_proxy_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER multicorn OPTIONS (wrapper 'yam_fdw.Yamfdw');

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE event_warnings ( 
"_id" varchar OPTIONS (type 'ObjectId'),
"ID" varchar, "Point" varchar,
"Start_Time" timestamptz, "Stop_Time" timestamptz, "Area" varchar,
"Value" float, "Station" varchar, "Device" varchar, "Warning_Type" varchar,
"Warning_Upper_Limit" float, "Warning_Lower_Limit" float,
"Warning_Method" int
)

SERVER mongodb_proxy_server OPTIONS ( 
db 'XXX', collection 'event_warnings', 
host '122.XXX.XXX.XXX', port '27017', user 'username', password 'password'
);
```

**In superset**

[Successfully load the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCDcc.png)

But the foreign table only appears in the slices section. In the SQL lab tab,

[No foreign table appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0REj.png)

Anyone knows how to make the foreign table appears in the SQL lab tab ?

OS: Mac 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to synchronize your data to a PostgreSQL database.

We assembled an open-source platform to do that here https://github.com/pajachiet/mongo_sql_analytics_platform